# CGImageCreate Column Based Image Format

Tags: c, core-graphics, cgimage

I have image data stored in a column based format and am trying to draw it directly using `CGImageCreate`.

For a 3x3 rendered image:

```
A B C
D E F
G H I
```

The data is stored in columns, bottom to top:

```
data[] = { G, D, A, H, E, B, I, F, C };
```

I know that I can transpose the data to a format that CGImage understands, but is there a way to skip this step and let  `CGImageCreate` know about this data format so that I can pass `data` to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is change the direction that the image is rendered, you can do that by just drawing the image rotated or flipped, as necessary. [CGContextRotateCTM](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextRotateCTM) can be used to rotate the coordinates in the context before drawing.